# How to form java.util.Date calls in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, java.util.date

I have been successfully using `java.util.Date`, and I would prefer to keep using it. Basically, I am having trouble forming the method calls to a class.

I basically want to feed a date like `2014-08-06` into my Clojure program which will override using today as the date. This is so I can form a SQL query. I'm just not sure how to use the Java calls in Clojure.

```
(def x1 (SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

I just don't know how to form the parse.

Here's my core.clj

```
(ns util.core
  ^{:author "Charles M. Norton",
    :doc "util is a Clojure utilities directory containing things
          most Clojure programs need, like cli routines.
        Created on April 4, 2012"}

  (:require [clojure.string :as cstr]
            [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
            [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:import java.util.Date)
  (:import java.text.SimpleDateFormat)
  (:import java.text.ParseException)
  (:import java.io.File)
  (:use clojure-csv.core))
```

Here is the Java code

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    java.util.Date d = sdf.parse("12/12/2003");
```

Comment: parse call will be `(.parse x1 "2014-08-06")`

Comment: The above duplicate is also your question @octopusgrabbus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is parse call in `lein repl`

```
user=> (def x1 (SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd"))
#'user/x1
user=> (.parse x1 "2014-08-06")
#inst "2014-08-05T21:00:00.000-00:00"
user=> (type (.parse x1 "2014-08-06"))
java.util.Date
```

read http://clojure.org/java_interop to know how to translate java code.

Comment: Thank you. I also wanted a pointer to some instructions. I know how to call a single object, but I forgot about how to order the method with the instance. Again, many thanks.